# (object) is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, asp.net

My intellisense is giving me the error:
'ClassLibrary1.GetTimeZone.myWorldTime' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: My code]

!Object Browser for the class[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAqfa.jpg)
[image: My code]

Comment: Please post code as _code_ not as an image. You are also delimiting the string with `char` delimiters - this will not compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to put the line in error in a class constructor or a method.

Comment: I had tried the static method during my hour of messing, you spotted the part that was messing me up, thanks

Answer (score 9):

`LoadData` is a [*static*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) method. You call it on the type, not an instance.

```
ChaosSoftware.WorldTime.LoadData("worldtime.xml");
```

This needs to be placed inside a method in order to execute (constructor or other method).

Additionally, though not the reason for the error, you should use `"` to delimit a string. In C#, single quotes are for character literals (that is, single characters). What you have will not compile.

Comment: Correct, but this alone won't be enough. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8908843/447356) makes it complete.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for your answer, I had tried that before, it was Baboon's addition which was really catching me out

Answer (score 0):

LoadData seems to be a static function, so you should do this instead (without an object instance):

```
ChaosSoftware.WorldTime.LoadData("blahblah...");
```