# C# array is a field but is used like a type

Tags: c#, arrays, string, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(object) is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908803/object-is-a-field-but-is-used-like-a-type)

As you might have guessed from the title am I getting this error:

```
Invasion_server.variables.resources is a field but is used like a type
```

The code that is giving me that error is:

```
class variables
{
    ....
    public static string[] resources = new string[30];
    resources[0] = "cities_wood";
    ....
}
```

Could someone please tell me what is causing the problem, because elsewhere in the code it is working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to initialize the members of the array outside of a constructor or method body, you would need to do so using the initializer syntax with the declaration:

```
class variables
{ 
  public static string[] resources = new string[30] 
  { 
    "item one",
    "item two",
    ...
  }
}
```

The downside to doing so is that you'd be required to populate all 30 values.  If you're looking to just populate the first, then you'll need to do so either in a constructor or method body.  You could consider a static constructor, which would have the same net effect as initializing when declared;  the static constructor is run the first time a member of the class is accessed.  For example:

```
class variables
{
  public static string[] resources;

  static variables()
  {
    resources = new string[30];
    resources[0] = "item one";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do this in some method

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class variables
{
    public static string[] resources = new string[30];

    static void doSomething() {
        resources[0] = "cities_wood";
    }
}
```

you were not assigning the variable within a class constructor or a method.

Comment: can you reach a static variable from nonstatic function?

Comment: @StackUser yes nonstatic can see static, but static cannot see nonstatic

Comment: @StackUser thank you edited answer. was typing fast

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're trying to do operations on a variable in the class body, rather than in a method. You should only have a few things in your class body:

1. Fields:   `int myField = 0;`
2. Methods:  `public void myMethod(){  }`
3. Constructors/Destructors  (just a special type of method): `public MyClass(){}`

So when the compiler sees anything that is the first word following a `;` (meaning that it is the first word of a new line of code), it expects to see either an identifier like `public`, `static`, etc, or a `Type`, like `int`. Since it wasn't an identifier, it looked for a type, and since it wasn't a type, you got your error.

Hope that explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do

```
resources[0] = "cities_wood";
```

in your class definition. Do it in a static constuctor or using a list initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the fields in a method or constructor or all in the declaration like

```
class variables

    {
         public static string[] resources = new string[30];

        public variables()
        { 
           resources[0] = "cities_wood";
        }
    }
```

OR

```
 public static string[] resources = {"cities_wood", "....", "more stuff", "and more stuff"};//Your 30 or les or more variables separated by a comma
```