# 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting an error message that I can't seem to figure out. I see that there are many other similar questions posted but the solutions don't seem to be working for me.

Error Message:

```
'PaymentPlanStoreLogic.Class1.myLog' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

My Code:

```
using System;
using PaymentPlanLogic;
namespace PaymentPlanStoreLogic
{
  public class Class1
  {
    Logger myLog = new Logger();
    myLog.createLog();
   }
}
```

Object Browser:

```
public void createLog()
Member of PaymentPlanLogic.Logger
```

I have tried the following as suggested on the page 
[(object) is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908803/object-is-a-field-but-is-used-like-a-type)

```
PaymentPlanLogic.Logger.createLog();
```

But I get the error

```
"'PaymentPlanLogic.Logger.createLog()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'"
```

Comment: Should you not have that code in Class1 inside of a constructor ? The first line will create a private member in your class, but the second line does not make any sense and hence you are getting this error.

Comment: If this is your complete code, I would suggest looking at a few [C# tutorial sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't call a method on a field outside of a method:

```
using System;
using PaymentPlanLogic;
namespace PaymentPlanStoreLogic
{
  public class Class1
  {
    Logger myLog = new Logger();

    void YouForgotThisMethod()
    {
      myLog.createLog();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: YouForgotThisMethod is probably the constructor that is missing (I think).

Comment: @ken2k Yes you are probably right, doesn't have to be in a constructor though so I gave the general answer

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing something stupid.

Answer (score 15):

Tobsey's answer is correct. The reason for the odd error message is because the compiler is trying desperately to figure out what you mean. The reasoning goes like this:

> The only things that are legal at this point are declarations of classes, interfaces, structs, enums, fields, operators, indexers, events, properties, methods, constructors and destructors. It can't be a class, interface, struct or enum because those all have a keyword in them. It can't be a constructor or destructor. Therefore the user must be attempting to make a field, operator, indexer, event, property or method. All of those things may legally begin with a type. OK, so this expression must be attempting to identify a type. But it doesn't identify a type; it identifies a field. So that's the error I'll give.

Of course that is an unjustified anthropomorphization of the compiler, but you take the point: the compiler's "mental model" of erroneous code is very different from what you were thinking when you wrote the broken code, and so the error message is not very helpful. *The compiler thinks that you know that a statement can't go there, and have mixed up a field with a type.* A more sophisticated algorithm would have the compiler guess that since what you typed is a legal statement, that the real error is that the statement is outside of a block.

Writing error message generators that accurately model the mental processes of people who are writing broken code is quite difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `Class1` is incomplete. You cannot call this method within the class, you can call it within a method of the class:

```
using System;
using PaymentPlanLogic;
namespace PaymentPlanStoreLogic
{
    public class Class1
    {
        #region Members

        Logger myLog;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public Class1()
        {
            myLog = new Logger();
            myLog.createLog();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then `createLog()` would execute upon instantiating a new instance of Class1.