# How to set DatePicker selectable range for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, datetimepicker

I'm searching everywhere on forums and msdn and it says that SelectedDate, DisplayStartDate, DisplayEndDate, whether in XAML or C# will make it work, but everytime I try to use any of theses, I'm getting missing directive reference or assembly. How do I fix this? I know I'm missing a reference, but what using System or xlmns....? Please tell me how I can make it work, so I don't get errors when I try to use the property.

**XAML Code & References:**

```
x:Class="Data_Query.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dateOfBirthPicker" ValueChanged="dateOfBirthPicker_ValueChanged" Margin="0,369,0,0"/>
```

**C# Code References:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Media; // added to support SolidColorBrush, FontWeights, etc...
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Data_Query.Resources;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

**Full XAML Code:**

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="JP APPS" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Data Query" Margin="0,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--Height of the Grid has to be greater than the ScrollViewer's Height to make it scrollable.-->
    <!--Removing the ScrollViewer's Height enables you to see the entire page in a transparent-like view-->
    <ScrollViewer Height="605" Width="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-163" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid MinHeight="605" Height="770">
            <TextBlock x:Name="firstNameTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="First Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTB" InputScope="PersonalFullName" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" LostFocus="firstNameTB_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lastNameTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,119,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Last Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTB" InputScope="PersonalFullName" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" LostFocus="lastNameTB_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,151,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="emailAddressTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,228,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email Address:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="emailAddressTB" InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" LostFocus="emailAddressTB_LostFocus"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,260,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="dateOfBirthTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,337,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Date of Birth:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <toolkit:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="dateOfBirthPicker" ValueChanged="dateOfBirthPicker_ValueChanged" Margin="0,369,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Name="genderTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,447,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Gender:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton Name="maleRB" GroupName="genderLB" Tap="maleRB_Tap" Content="Male" Checked="maleRB_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton Name="femaleRB" GroupName="genderLB" Tap="femaleRB_Tap" Content="Female" Checked="femaleRB_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock Name="disabilityTBL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,551,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Do you have a disability?" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ToggleButton Name="yesTBU" Content="Yes" Tap="ToggleButton_Tap" Checked="yesTBU_Checked" Height="100" Width="150" Margin="0,583,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ToggleButton Name="noTBU" Content="No" Tap="ToggleButton_Tap" Checked="noTBU_Checked"  Height="100" Width="150" Margin="151,583,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,250,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="submitButton" Height="77"/>
            <Button Content="Reset All" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="235,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="resetButton" Height="77"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: make DatePicker readonly, and set today's date by default...

Comment: what do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Without trying to sound critical, can you explain why you need to use a DatePicker if you're not actually going to let them pick the date?  If there is not an explicit requirement for DatePicker a read-only text box should suffice.

Comment: I am doing a dateOfBirthPicker and want to limit selectable options only to today's date, that's why.

Comment: Alternatively, as ArsenMkrt suggested, you could set IsReadOnly="True" on the DatePicker control itself.  And even with a read-only text box, you could default the value to today, but it's totally up to you.

Comment: So... the user can set his date of birth only on his birthday?

Comment: I can't, it says this member "IsReadOnly=True" is not recognizable or accessible onto DatePicker.

Comment: The user can set any date but up to today's date, you can't be born tomorrow today.

Comment: So you would really prefer to establish a range of valid dates for your DatePicker (today being the latest, and some other date being the earliest)?

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you targeting?  I believe the Datepicker wasn't available until version 4.

Comment: @alan yes that is correct, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TrueEddie I'm not sure, but I believe it's the latest one. DatePicker does function, but just want to limit options up to today's date and not future dates on dateOfBirthPicker.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using WPF you do not need to be using the toolkit namespace which points to the windows phone. 
In the example project I am working with this is all I have to do to get the DatePicker working.

```
<Window x:Class="testDatePicker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <DatePicker DisplayDateStart="2014/02/28" DisplayDateEnd="2014/02/28" SelectedDate="2014/02/28"></DatePicker>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I copied and paste your code into a new project and it said that Window and DatePicker cannot be found, make sure that all assemblies have been built. What assembly reference is it talking about?

Comment: You can't just copy and past my code, unless you have a x:Class="testDatePicker.MainWindow". If you create a wpf project in 2013 you should be able to paste only the DatePicker line and that should work. Note the Datepicker is a standard control in WPF, from your namespacing above it would seem you might be working on windows phone.

Comment: I did try to copy and paste only the DatePicker but it says The type 'DatePicker' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: You are not creatign a wpf application, you are creating a windows phone application. Which allows you to change Value (Date You are dealing with is for windows phone). And it does not have the fields you are looking for. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/WindowsPhone7/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/DateTimePickers/DateTimePickerBase.cs

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to only be able to select today, then they really can't select anything. Set the default value to be DateTime.Today and set IsEnabled="false" on the control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop people from selecting any date beyond today, then you can use the `BlackoutDates` property of a `DatePicker`. Like this:

```
myDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.MaxValue));
```

You should do this around the time the page is initialised.

Comment: there are 4 errors in the code you gave me,
1) 'dateOfBirthPicker' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'.
2) CalendarDateRange Method must have a return type.
3) Now represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day.
4) MaxValue is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'.
Any solutions?

Comment: Something in your code is desperately wrong ... what does the code behind of your xaml look like? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154567/field-but-is-used-like-a-type

Comment: I added the full xaml code in the post above for you to analyze, by looking the link you provided, I managed to the solve the field used like type error, but now 2 errors remaining on BlackoutDates `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker' does not contain a definition for 'BlackoutDates' and no extension method 'BlackoutDates' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `The type or namespace name 'CalendarDateRange' cound not be found for the same reason.`

Comment: (btw: 'code behind' != xaml, it is the xaml.cs file). Sorry I didn't notice the reference to this being a phone version of the control and assumed it was a full datepicker. I don't know if that supports the BlackoutDates property, it doesn't look like it. Full datepicker is here, but don't know about phone version http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx