# C# Class instance not accessible under same namespace and same project library

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLib1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
       Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
        obj1.

    }
}
```

I have added a class library project in the solution and created 2 classes under same namespace.

As per the code showing above, I am creating instance of Class1 and trying to access the properties of **Class1** inside **Class2**.

But I am not getting the object 'obj1' in the intellisense and not able to access the properties of Class1.

Suppose if I add one Console project into the same solution and if I try to access the same (in Static void Main( arg []) method), by adding the reference of this Class Library, I am able to access the object of Class1 and properties.

Hi friends, I am expecting your help on this case, that why I am not able to access the object of a Class in another Class those are in same namespace and same project library? If any mistakes is there in my approach, please correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't write statements directly in the class body, only declarations; statements have to be in a method.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154567/field-but-is-used-like-a-type) question in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class `Class2` wrong. You can't access the field in class declaration scope. Enclose your code in method/property.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Class2
{
   Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
    obj1.

}
```

Should be:

```
public class Class2
  {
     Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
      public void someMethod(){
          obj1.ID = 1;
       }

  }
```