# "is a field and used like a type" error

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `StringBuilder` in a C# Class Library project. I have added the `using` statement and all. I am not getting intellisense and I am getting a compile error.

Eg:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("");
```

I am seeing an error on the variable `sb`, that

> `sb` is a field and used like a type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your using statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(object) is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908803/object-is-a-field-but-is-used-like-a-type)

Answer (score 4):

Without looking at your complete code I can only guess that you are writing your code directly in the class, Following line should be inside a method

```
sb.Append("");
```

For the class it should be like:

```
using System.Text; //make sure this is included. 
public class MyClass
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  public MyClass() //Constructor
  {
   sb.Append(""); //this statement should be inside a method
  }
}
```

Currently it would be like:

[image]

Comment: That was it.Good Catch, Thanks Habib.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `StringBuilder` class you need to reference it's library properly.

Add `using System.Text;` to the top of your class